# After click A redirect to url and find id and use it automaticly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to sites, but i need when i click on a href(where is url to another site with #idexample) and after redirect to currect page will find that id and click on it automaticly (next a but no href this time).
More info in image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2iUw.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Luca i tried that id but it doesnt work and dont know how to do it....another way..

Comment: Then do your research before coming here

Comment: @Luca i was looking for something but nothing to find...

Answer (score 0):

Add a param to that URL, for example:

```
http://www.myurl.com?param=foo
```

And then in the site read that param to do a different behavior, like explained here: [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: i have these things there http://prntscr.com/j7c1s9 can i use something from that?

Comment: You should add the param in the href param, for example `<a class="filtrBut" href="http://www.myurl.com?param=foo" id="foo">`